# Mousewheel not working on TinyScollbar jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i have attached TinyScrollBar(from [[here]](http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/)) plugin with my project. It was **working some days ago**, but suddenly, i found its not working. **Other parts of plugin r working as m able to move my div container**, but **MouseWheel** event is not working.
When i start debugging plugin, "oEvent" agrument of "wheel" function return this

({originalEvent:({}), type:"DOMMouseScroll", isDefaultPrevented:function J() {return !1;}, timeStamp:19693531, jQuery171048684756025579645:true, which:1, view:#1=({}), target:({}), shiftKey:false, relatedTarget:null, metaKey:false, eventPhase:3, currentTarget:({}), ctrlKey:false, cancelable:true, bubbles:true, altKey:false, srcElement:(void 0), relatedNode:(void 0), attrName:(void 0), attrChange:(void 0)})

But when i create a new project with only "TinyScrollbar" plugin, its working fine and "oEvent" agrument of "wheel" function return this

({originalEvent:({}), type:"DOMMouseScroll", timeStamp:1326705353897, jQuery1326705156319:true, which:1, wheelDelta:(void 0), view:#1=({}), toElement:(void 0), target:#11=({}), srcElement:(void 0), shiftKey:false, screenY:273, screenX:234, relatedTarget:null, relatedNode:(void 0), prevValue:(void 0), pageY:139, pageX:234, originalTarget:#11#, offsetY:(void 0), offsetX:(void 0), newValue:(void 0), metaKey:false, layerY:119, layerX:226, keyCode:(void 0), handler:(void 0), fromElement:(void 0), eventPhase:3, detail:-3, data:(void 0), currentTarget:({}), ctrlKey:false, clientY:139, clientX:234, charCode:(void 0), cancelable:true, button:0, bubbles:true, attrName:(void 0), attrChange:(void 0), altKey:false})

What i found in debugging is, "oEvent.detail" & some other "oEvent" object properties is not there. i am sure, i didn't call e.PreventDefault() anywhere for any div.

I am using these plugins:

1. jquery-1.7.1.min.js
2. jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
3. mustache.js
4. jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js
5. jquery.scrollablecombo.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved..**

Actually, **Tiny Scrollbar Plugin in combo with jquery 1.7 broke the scroll feature**. This has been resolved in tinyscrollbar 1.66 !

Thankx to TinyScrollBar Developer, who replied my mail quickly....
May be this info helps someone...